# send multiple files to server with websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to send multiple files to the server through WebSocket.
And this is something I came up with so far. But it does not do the job properly.

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var conn;
                var server_msg = document.getElementById("server_msg");

                function sendFile(i) {
                    indx = i.toString();
                    var file = document.getElementById("image"+indx).files[0];

                    if (!file) {
                        conn.send("none");
                    } else {
                        conn.send(indx+file.name);
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();

                        reader.loadend = function() {

                        }
                        reader.onload = function(e) {
                            rawData = e.target.result;
                            conn.send(rawData);
                        }
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
                    if (!conn) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                        sendFile(i);
                    }
                    return false;
                };

                if (window["WebSocket"]) {
                    conn = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/ws");
                    conn.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
                    conn.onopen = function (evt) {
                        server_msg.innerHTML = "<b>Connection opened.</b>";
                        return false;
                    };
                    conn.onmessage = function (evt) {
                        server_msg.innerHTML = evt.data;
                        return false;
                    };
                    conn.onclose = function (evt) {
                        server_msg.innerHTML = "<b>Connection closed.</b>";
                        return false;
                    };
                    conn.onerror = function (evt) {
                        server_msg.innerHTML = "<b>Error happened!!!</b>" + evt.value;
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    server_msg.innerHTML = "<b>Your browser does not support WebSockets.</b>";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="server_msg"></div>
        <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1"> <br>
            <input type="file" id="image2" name="image2"> <br>
            <input type="file" id="image3" name="image3"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

And this is how I handle it on the server-side:

```
app.Get("/ws", websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()

    for ind := 1; ind < 4; ind++ {
        // step-1: check if filename is null
        _, msg, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Producer: read error 1 - ", err)
            return
        }
        filename := string(msg)
        log.Printf("Producer: recieved filename - %s", filename)

        if filename != "none" {
            // step-2: read image bytes
            _, img_bytes, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Producer: read error 2 - ", err)
                return
            }
            log.Println("Producer: recieved raw data")

            // step-3: save image
            fp, err := os.Create(filename)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            _, err2 := fp.Write(img_bytes)
            if err2 != nil {
                log.Fatal(err2)
            }
            fp.Close()
        }
    }
}))
```

I think the issue is inside `sendFile` function when I read the buffer.
But I can not figure out how to solve it.

How should I send files separately?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that this:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    rawData = e.target.result;
    conn.send(rawData);
}
```

will be called right after this:

```
conn.send(indx+file.name);
```

But apparently that was not the case. All of the `reader.onload` are called at the very end. So I had to change the server-side like this:

```
var filenames []string
for ind := 1; ind < 4; ind++ {
    // step-1: check if filename is null
    _, msg, err := c.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Producer: read error 1 - ", err)
        return
    }
    filename := string(msg)
    filenames = append(filenames, filename)
    log.Printf("Producer: recieved filename - %s", filename)
}
for _, filename := range filenames {
    if filename != "none" {
        // step-2: read image bytes
        _, img_bytes, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Producer: read error 2 - ", err)
            return
        }
        log.Println("Producer: recieved raw data")

        // step-3: save image
        fp, err := os.Create(filename)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        _, err2 := fp.Write(img_bytes)
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Fatal(err2)
        }
        fp.Close()
    }
}
```